Dataflow thread safe db context
My app receives multiple files (50 files, each file with 1000 rows) and processes them in Dataflow blocks. In one of the blocks UploadToDatabaseBlock, I set MaxDegreeOfParalellism to 8. This creates multiple threads which add files to the database using EntityFramework. Database context is set to Scoped.
Since its Scoped, I get exception A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Because the services use repositories which use the same db context for one API request.
The problem seems universal: how to use Dataflow blocks (TPL multiple threads) with EntityFramework and its DbContext.
Dataflow main method code:
ApplicationFileService.cs
public void UploadApplicationFiles(List<AplicationFileDTO> inputFiles)
{
    var invalidFiles = new ConcurrentQueue<ApplicationFile>();

    var sendFileToBlobBlock = new TransformBlock<ApplicationFileDTO, ApplicationFile>(async appFile =>
    {
        await azureBlobService.SendBlobAsync(appFile.FileContent);
        return ConstructDatabaseFile();
    });
    var saveFileToDatabaseBlock = new ActionBlock<ApplicationFile>(async appFileDb =>
    {
        try {
            SaveFileToDb(appFileDb); // unitOfWork.FilesRepository.AddFileAsync()
            await unitOfWork.FileRowsRepository.SaveRowsToDbAsync(appFileDb.Rows);
            await mediator.Send(new MarkFileCompleteRequest(appFileDb.Id));
            IsFileComplete(appFileDb);
            await unitOfWork.CommitChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            // unitOfWork rollback
            // azureBlobService.DeleteAsync(appFileDb.BlobPath);
            invalidFiles.Add(appFileDb);
        }
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = SystemInfo.CpuCores });
    // Link blocks
    // Post each file from input list to first block 'sendFileToBlobBlock'
}

Solutions I found:

Set DbContext to Transient in ASP .NET Dependency Injection.

Instantiate a DbContext per thread.
PRO: I read online this is the preferred way.
CONS:
I use many services during upload. I call a private method which calls another method which calls different services classes, etc.
I managed to make it work by creating a static class AmbientScope and providing the thread-scoped services in each method.


public void IsFileComplete() {
    var serviceA = AmbientServiceScope.Current?.GetRequiredService<IServiceA>();
    var serviceB = AmbientServiceScope.Current?.GetRequiredService<IServiceB>();
    var serviceC = AmbientServiceScope.Current?.GetRequiredService<IServiceC>();
    var mediator = AmbientServiceScope.Current?.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
    if (serviceA is null || serviceB is null || ...)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No ambient scope available!");
    }
    // continue method logic
    // public method because its used by other services/requests to check a file is complete, 
    // not only by UploadWithDataflow
}

Problems:

It is a lot of boilerplate code.
If a method is used from multiple API requests (Upload files, Check file complete), then the requests which do not use threads still need to create an Ambient Scope to work.
I need again boilerplate code and to inject IServiceScopeFactory everywhere:

using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
using (AmbientServiceScope.SetScope(scope.ServiceProvider))
{
...
}

This is such a common problem. There must be an easy solution.
AmbientScope
public static class AmbientServiceScope
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<IServiceProvider?> _currentScope = new();

    public static IServiceProvider? Current => _currentScope.Value;

    public static IDisposable SetScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var previous = _currentScope.Value;
        _currentScope.Value = serviceProvider;

        return new DisposeAction(() => _currentScope.Value = previous);
    }

    private class DisposeAction(Action disposeAction) : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose() => disposeAction();
    }
}


I do not understand why AmbientServiceScope is needed? Looks like a hack.

Now that you said, I think AmbientServiceScope is not needed. But still only with ServiceScopeFactory I have to get injected services in each method as with the ambient scope.

Are you sure you want to run a bunch of database queries in parallel? IO tend to not parallelize as well as compute. Have you done any profiling/measurements/benchmarking to confirm that multi threading will help for your use case?

I receive 50 files and each file has 1000 rows. I parallelized the 50 files batch and it improved performance. I need to do it for the 1000 rows because they are sent to Blob storage and that operation is very costly.

The entire idea is wrong - and I use Dataflow pipelines to parse large files and bulk import hundreds of thousands of rows every day. DbContext isn't a connection, it's a Unit of Work. Dataflow is meant for dataflow pipelines, not parallelizing code. Executing multiple UPDATEs in parallel only results in increased blocking, not improved performance

50 files by 1K rows is no data at all, no matter how big they are. You don't need import parallelization to begin with. The fast and scalable way to import and update data is to import it into a staging table, eg using SqlBulkCopy, then update the target. And if you really have a lot of data you can use eg partition switching in SQL Server to move the staging table directly into the target.

A proper Dataflow architecture would be to eg download multiple files concurrently (DOP>=1) and link the download block to a TransformManyBlock (DOP>=1) that parses the file and emits individual rows to a BatchBlock. That BatchBlock feeds an ActionBlock with DOP=1 which uses SqlBulkCopy to import the batches into a staging table. This way you can download and parse files as fast as possible, while importing it in the fastest way the database offers. Once this process completes, you update the target

PS: Where's the actual Dataflow code? What's the actual business problem? The question contains only concepts that have nothing to do with dataflows and are even antipatterns, like using CRUD "repositories" over the high-level Unit-of-Work. You don't need any kind of Mediator either, messages in a Dataflow pipeline flow from block to block along links

I have added the Dataflow code.

My database operations are slow and I wanted to parallelize somehow. That was main thinking. Dataflow offers MaxDegreeOfParallelism option and besides that by separating into blocks you get additional paralellization. I saw Dataflow easier than using simple TPL with Task.Run. And I would have the same DbContext problems.
MediatR was an ugly attempt to fix by moving every service call to mediatr. To avoid creating scoped services for each thread and by creating only a scoped mediator per thread. If my Dataflow is wrong you are welcome to correct me.


@PanagiotisKanavos your comment explaining the whole process is very helpful. I added the dataflow code at the start of the question if it helps. If the answer to my question is that Dataflow should never use UoW, Transactions, DbContext operations but rather a Staging table I would consider it valid if indeed this is the right way. There are also parallelized queries PLINQ but I think they are out of scope of this question.

Each parallel thread needs its own DbContext as a single scoped context isn't thread safe. This can be a nuisance when the thread worker needs to call various methods that would normally access a single, injected, module-level DbContext instance as you would need to pass the tightly-scoped per-thread DbContext instance to each such method.
A unit of work pattern implementation that I adopted some time ago can assist with this as it would work similar to your ambient service scope. DbContextScope. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zejji.DbContextScope.EFCore)
Rather than injecting a DbContext via your container, DbContextScope works in two parts.  A DbContextScopeFactory (creates scopes/UoW) and an AmbientDbContextLocator to retrieve a DbContext instance from within a scope.  Normally this is useful for having a Unit of Work /w a Repository pattern, but it works very well for multi-thread scoping as well.
Both of those dependencies get registered with the IoC container. Scoped lifespan is fine for each. There is also a DbContextFactory interface you can extend if there are specific setup needed for the DbContext initialization itself when the DbContextScope needs to create an instance.
Given a class that has a thread worker method that will need to scope a DbContext for that thread/operation and several worker methods that want to access that scoped DbContext:
public class ThreadWorker(IDbContextScopeFactory _contextScopeFactory, IAmbientDbContextLocator _contextLocator)
{
    private AppDbContext Context => _contextLocator.Get<AppDbContext>();

    public async Task DoWork()
    {
        using var contextScope = _contextScopeFactory.Create();
        await doSomething();
        await doSomethingElse();
        await contextScope.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    
    private async Task doSomething()
    {
        var foo = await Context.Foos.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        // ...
    }

    private async Task doSomethingElse()
    {
        var bar = await Context.Bars.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        // ...
    }
}

Here you access the DbContext through the locator which gives you a DbContext scoped to any existing DbContextScope. If you were to try and access "Context" without first creating a scope, you get an exception. This way any worker methods or repository classes etc. can access a single scoped DbContext similar to an injected DbContext, while the worker thread method controls the scope, ensuring each thread has an isolated scope and resulting DbContext.
